# How do I find the difference between two strings and return the difference value?

Tags: javascript, string

I can compare the length but, I can't return mismatch value.

```js
var str1 ="zoho";
var str2 ="zogo";

//find the mismatched one
let output = hg;
let names = "zoho";
let nam2= "zogo"
let rest = names.match(nam2)
 
console.log(rest);
```

Comment: What's the expected result if the two variables not have the same length?

Comment: Use a loop and compare each character at same index and return the values which are different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Covering length of strings are same/different cases;

```js
const findDifference = (str1, str2) => {
  let result = "";
  if (str1.length >= str2.length) {
     str1.split("").forEach((char, index) => {
      if (char!=str2[index]) {
        result = result + char + (str2[index] || '');
      }
     });
  } else {
    str2.split("").forEach((char, index) => {
      if (char!=str1[index]) {
        result = result + (str1[index] || "") + char;
      }
     });
  }
  return result;
}
 
console.log(findDifference("zoho", "zogo"));
console.log(findDifference("zohox", "zogo"));
console.log(findDifference("zoho", "zogox"));
console.log(findDifference("zoho", ""));
console.log(findDifference("", "zogo"));
```

results are
`hg hgx hgx zoho zogo` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you expect the two strings have the same `length`, and the two words have the same characters sequence.

```js
const findDifference = (first, second) => {
  let diff = ''
  for (let i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    if (first[i] !== second[i]) {
      diff += first[i] + second[i];
    }
  }
  return diff
}

console.log(findDifference('zoho', 'zogo'));
```

Otherwise, If you want to check the two words similarity, I suggest you to check [Levenshtein distance](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/levenshtein-distance-in-javascript#:%7E:text=The%20Levenshtein%20distance%20is%20a,one%20word%20into%20the%20other.&text=We%20are%20required%20to%20write,the%20Levenshtein%20distance%20between%20them.)

Comment: This will not work if both the input strings does not have same length.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (This solution will also work if you have strings with different length) **:**

```js
var str1 ="zoho";
var str2 ="zogo";

let differenceValue = '';

Array(Math.max(str1.length, str2.length)).fill().forEach((v, index) => {
  if (str1[index] !== str2[index]) {
    differenceValue += (str1[index] ?? '') + (str2[index] ?? '');
  }
})

console.log(differenceValue);
```